# Informix one to many format issue

Tags: informix

Trying to fix my Informix query results format from a one to many relationship. My current query is using a JOIN but is creating a new line for every time there is a match to the JOIN ON condition.  I should add the below is only an example, the real data is thousands of entries with about a 100 unique "category" entries so I cant hard code WHERE statements, it needs to read each entry and add if a match. I tried a GROUP_CONCAT however is just returned an error, guess its not a informix function, I also tried reading this thread but have yet been unable to get working. [Show a one to many relationship as 2 columns - 1 unique row (ID & comma separated list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715350/show-a-one-to-many-relationship-as-2-columns-1-unique-row-id-comma-separate)

Any help will be appreciated.

- IBM/Informix-Connect Version 3.70.UC4
- IBM/Informix LIBGLS LIBRARY Version 5.00.UC5
- IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC8W1

Tables

movie

```
name    rating  movie_id
rio g   1   
horton  g   2
blade   r   3
lotr_1  pg13    4
lotr_2  pg13    5
paul_blart  pg  6
```

category

```
cat_name    id
kids    1
comedy  2
action  3
fantasy 4
```

category_member

```
movie_name  cat_name    catmem_id
lotr_1 action 1
lotr_1 fantasy 2
rio kids 3
rio comedy  4
```

When I use

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "SET isolation dirty read;
UNLOAD to /export/home/movie/movieDetail.unl DELIMITER ','
    SELECT a.name, a.rating, b.cat_name
      FROM movie a
      LEFT JOIN category b ON b.movie_name = a.name
;" | dbaccess thedb;
```

What I get is

```
rio,g,kids
rio,g,comedy
lotr_1,pg13,action
lotr_1,pg13,fantasy
```

What I would like is

```
rio,g,kids,comedy
lotr_1,pg13,action,fantasy
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Install the `GROUP_CONCAT` user-defined aggregate

You must install the `GROUP_CONCAT` user-defined aggregate from [SO 715350](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715350) (referenced in your question) into your database.  The `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate is not defined by Informix, but can be added if you use the SQL from that question.  One difference between that and a normal built-in function is that you need to install the aggregate in each database in the server where you need to use it.  There might be a way to do a 'global install' (for all databases in a given server), but I've forgotten (or, more accurately, never learned) how to do it.

#### Writing your queries

With the sample database listed at the bottom:

1. The query in the question does not run:

   ```
   SELECT a.name, a.rating, b.cat_name
     FROM movie a
     LEFT JOIN category b ON b.movie_name = a.name;
   SQL -217: Column (movie_name) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
   ```
2. This can be fixed by changing `category` to `category_member`.  This produces:

   ```
   SELECT a.name, a.rating, b.cat_name
     FROM movie a
     LEFT JOIN category_member b ON b.movie_name = a.name;
   rio           g       kids
   rio           g       comedy
   horton        g
   blade         r
   lotr_1        pg13    action
   lotr_1        pg13    fantasy
   lotr_2        pg13
   paul_blart    pg
   ```
3. The LEFT JOIN appears to be unwanted.  And using `GROUP_CONCAT` produces approximately the desired answer:

   ```
   SELECT a.name, a.rating, GROUP_CONCAT(b.cat_name)
     FROM movie a
     JOIN category_member b ON b.movie_name = a.name
    GROUP BY a.name, a.rating;
   rio          g       kids,comedy
   lotr_1       pg13    action,fantasy
   ```
4. If you specify the delimiter as `,`, the commas in the data from the `GROUP_CONCAT` operator will be escaped to avoid ambiguity:

   ```
   SELECT a.NAME, a.rating, GROUP_CONCAT(b.cat_name)
     FROM movie a
     JOIN category_member b ON b.movie_name = a.NAME
    GROUP BY a.NAME, a.rating;
   rio,g,kids\,comedy
   lotr_1,pg13,action\,fantasy
   ```

   Within standard Informix utilities, there isn't a way to avoid that; they don't leave the selected/unloaded data in an ambiguous format.
5. I'm not convinced that the database schema is very well organized.  The Movie table is OK; the Category table is OK; but the Category_Member table would be more orthodox if it used the schema:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category_member;
   CREATE TABLE category_member
   (
       movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Movie(Movie_id),
       category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Category(Id),
       PRIMARY KEY(movie_id, category_id)
   );
   INSERT INTO category_member VALUES(4, 3);
   INSERT INTO category_member VALUES(4, 4);
   INSERT INTO category_member VALUES(1, 1);
   INSERT INTO category_member VALUES(1, 2);

   -- Use GROUP_CONCAT
   SELECT a.NAME, a.rating, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name)
     FROM movie a
     JOIN category_member b ON b.movie_id = a.movie_id
     JOIN category c ON b.category_id = c.id
    GROUP BY a.NAME, a.rating;
   ```

   The output from this query is the same as from the previous one, but the joining is more orthodox.

#### Sample database

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie;
CREATE TABLE movie
(
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    rating CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    movie_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES("rio", "g", 1);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES("horton", "g", 2);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES("blade", "r", 3);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES("lotr_1", "pg13", 4);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES("lotr_2", "pg13", 5);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES("paul_blart", "pg", 6);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;
CREATE TABLE category
(
    cat_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO category VALUES("kids", 1);
INSERT INTO category VALUES("comedy", 2);
INSERT INTO category VALUES("action", 3);
INSERT INTO category VALUES("fantasy", 4);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category_member;
CREATE TABLE category_member
(
    movie_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    cat_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    catmem_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO category_member VALUES("lotr_1", "action", 1);
INSERT INTO category_member VALUES("lotr_1", "fantasy", 2);
INSERT INTO category_member VALUES("rio", "kids", 3);
INSERT INTO category_member VALUES("rio", "comedy", 4);
```

Comment: Yea the included tables where a rushed example so may have had errors along with the select statement so thank you for the detailed explanation. i was afraid you were going to confirm what I had thought.  We have over 100 distributed systems with unique admins so will have to do a lot of convincing to get executed.

Comment: The GROUP_CONCAT simply needs to be installed as part of the next upgrade, when you install the updated software that uses it.  Yes, it is never actually quite that simple, but how do you deal with other SPL that you need to add to make the system work?  It needs to be handled carefully.