# Distinct first row and concat second row

Tags: sql, informix

I have the following problem with Informix

Fail:

```
client  username
ABC     usr1
ABC     usr2
CDF     usr3
CDF     usr4
```

Correct:

```
client  username
ABC     usr1, usr2
CDF     usr3, usr4
```

What is the query correct to obtain the correct result?

Comment: Post the query you tried as part of the answer

Comment: Check [**SO - 715350**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715350/show-a-one-to-many-relationship-as-2-columns-1-unique-row-id-comma-separate). Informix does not have an aggregate similar to `GROUP_CONCAT`but you can create your own.

Comment: Note that the GROUP_CONCAT operator doesn't normally include a space after the comma separator.  It would be possible to define it so that it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client, GROUP_CONCAT(username)
  FROM someTable
 GROUP BY client;
```

does that works ?

Comment: Only if you've defined `GROUP_CONCAT` as a user-defined aggregate.