# Correct query to return 1 row, instead of duplicates when 2 columns out of many are constant

Tags: sql, informix

I have a query with 2 constant columns and another column with different values.

I am having issues with an informix query where for the same id, and name I am getting >1 rows returned because of 3rd select which is causing duplicates.

for example, my query is as below

```
select
x.id,
x.name
case when (y.tag = 'a') then z.value else '' as A
case when (y.tag = 'b') then z.value else '' as B
case when (y.tag = 'c') then z.value else '' as C
...

From
table x,
join table y on (x.<something> = y.<something>)
join table z on (y.<something> = z.<something>)

Where
x.name = "Test"
```

The result query returns 3 rows. Each row has a value of either A,B or C. The id and name is always the same and will be.

Basically instead of wanting 1 row returned with all the columns filled, its returning 3 becuase of the different z.value conditions

I want to sorta merge the 3 rows into 1 if that makes sense. There must be something simple or dumb I am missing that could fix this easily. Help please :)
Thanks

---

Apologies, I have added the result of my example query to better explain what its doing verses what I am i wanting:

**Result I get**

```
id   123
name qwe
A    z
B
C

id   123
name qwe
A
B    y
C

id   123
name qwe
A
B
C    x

3 Rows retrieved.
```

**Result I want**

```
id   123
name qwe
A    z
B    y
C    x

1 Row retrieved
```

Hope that clarifies any ambiguity

Comment: You want to make `a,b,c` become one? do you want to do by `sql` or `informix`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a one to many relationship as 2 columns - 1 unique row (ID & comma separated list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715350/show-a-one-to-many-relationship-as-2-columns-1-unique-row-id-comma-separate)

Comment: @dwir182 I have added the results of my query, What i am getting verses what I want. Hope that explains my question better. I will checkout the post you have linked as well. Thanks

Comment: Why is there a comma at the end of `from table x,`? is that just a mistake or is there a cross join involved? I suggest you need to provide **sample data** as well as the **expected result**

Comment: When you ask an SQL question, please provide skeletal schemas (relevant columns only) and sample data for all the tables involved in the query.  And please show SQL that runs and produces the claimed answer on the data shown.  I've no idea what the other two tables are doing in the query shown, but they affect what you see.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you simply want aggregation:

```
select x.id, x.name
       max(case when (y.tag = 'a') then z.value end) as A,
       max(case when (y.tag = 'b') then z.value end) as B,
       max(case when (y.tag = 'c') then z.value end) as C,
       ...
from table x join
     table y
     on (x.<something> = y.<something>) join
     table z
     on (y.<something> = z.<something>)
where x.name = 'Test'
group by x.name, x.id;
```